# How to send data from a user input field to a Next.js api route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, fetch-api

I am trying to send data from a user inputed input box on a client side webpage to a Next.js api route. However, when I send the input to the api route, the data does not populate in the api.

Here are the steps I am taking:

1. POST a url typed in by a user from an input field that is used to scrape data from that webpage

```js
// Component to handle url input 
//InputURL.js

import { useState } from "react";

export default function InputURL() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(`/api/data/url`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: url,
    });

    // 1. Send url to /api route for AXE CORE scraping
    console.log("URL sent to /api", url);
  };

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            onChange={(e) => setUrl(e.target.value)}
            type="url"
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
      </form>
  );
}
```

2. In an api route, I use the url to scrape data from the web page and then return the data

```js
// pages/api/data/url.js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const url = req?.body;
  const data = await getData(url);
  res.status(200).json(data);
}
```

In my terminal, I can see the url that was submitted, but when I go to localhost/api/data/url the url is not there.

Here is a screenshot of my api route in the browser:
[image]

Comment: You should look at the fetch api. It looks like you need to specify the content-type header and then stringify your data.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting data from `await getData(url);`?

Comment: Using your exact code I have no issues - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/next-js-using-pages-forked-ytlq9u